# How do I run hyperledger-fabric node js chaincode in dev mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to follow the tutorial here: [hyperledger-chaincode-for-developers](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#terminal-1-start-the-network)
But when I try to build my chaincode like this:

```
node main-chaincode.js --peer.address peer:7052
```

I get the following error message:

> Error: Illegal value for namevalue element of type string: undefined (not a string)                                         at fail (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:1817:23)            at Element.ProtoBuf.Reflect.ElementPrototype.verifyValue (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:1879:25)                                                                                   at Field.ProtoBuf.Reflect.FieldPrototype.verifyValue (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:3499:33)                                                                                       at Message.setter (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2582:77)                                                                                                                          at Function.start (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/chaincode.js:118:15)                                                                                                                          at start (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/main-chaincode.js:46:8)                                     at Object. (/opt/gopath/src/chaincode/lavinias_chaincode/node/main-chaincode.js:49:1)                        at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)                                                                                   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)                                                                     at Module.load (module.js:556:32):654:10)                                                                     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)

Here is my chaincode:

```
    'use strict';

const shim = require('fabric-shim');

const Chaincode = class {
  async Init(stub) {
       let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
       let args = ret.params;
       if(args.length != 2) {
         return shim.error("Error. Invalid call arguments.")
       }
       await stub.putState(args[0], Buffer.from(args[1]));

       return shim.success('Initialized Successfully!');
   }

   async Invoke(stub) {
       let functionAndParams = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
       if(functionAndParams.fcn === 'get') {
         return get(stub, functionAndParams.params);
       }
       else if(functionAndParams.fcn === 'set'){
         return set(stub, functionAndParams.params);
       }
       return shim.error("Error. Invalid invocation.");
   }
};

function get(stub, params) {
  if(params.length != 1) {
    return shim.error("Error. Invalid invocation call.");
  }
  return stub.getState(params[0]);
}

function set(stub, params) {
  if(params.length != 2) {
    return shim.error("Error. Invalid number of arguments.");
  }
  return stub.putState(params[0], params[1]);
}

var start = function start(){
  var cc = new Chaincode();
  shim.start(cc);
}

start();
```

The hyperledger shim docs say that only the peer.address argument is required: [shim.start](https://fabric-shim.github.io/Shim.html#.start__anchor)

Any help would be truly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by watching this video: [node chaincode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzwR0dwzXNs)
You are supposed to build it like this:

```
 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME="mycc:v0" node main-chaincode.js --peer.address peer:7052
```